# Angular binding property

Tags: angular, properties, binding

I'm trying to realize a property binding having my html builted dinamically in a service.

This line will work correctly when placed inside a component template:

```
<p [dtsSelectItem]="seq.documents[0]">{{ seq.documents[0] }}</p>
```

And Angular will recognize the property binding [dtsSelectItem].

But when I use the same line inside a service, it doesn't recognize the binding anymore.

myservice.service.ts

```
class SequenceViewerHelperReg {

 static getRow(spans: Array<string>, index: number): string {
 return `<div style="margin-bottom:0px;font-size: 0.65vw;">
    <div style="margin-right:10px;display:inline-block;width:2vw;text-align: right">
        <b>${index + 1}</b>
          <p [dtsSelectItem]="seq.documents[0]">TEST</p>
        </div>${spans.join('')}</div>`;
```

}

How can I implement a property binding inside the service? Is it something possible?

Comment: No angular can only bind to `template`/`templateUrl` provided. You can loop through your array of `spans` in your html template to get the required result.

Comment: rendering html as strings put into view doesn't let Angular compile them, so that's why they're not binded

Comment: Thank you very much at you both. This was the explanation I was looking for.